# iOS RestKit Merging Data

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using RestKit 0.10

I have an Entity named:  Message

Message has about 15 properties.

```
{
    user_id: "507deeaedc1362a42bd2e4ba",
    created_at: "2013-10-28T22:14:12.676Z",
    body: "some message",
    numberFollowers: 10,
    isHot: true,
    updated_at: "2013-10-28T22:14:12.676Z",
    _id: "526ee1b1ebf44af911010889"
    .....etc etc
}
```

I make a GET request to get the messages and everything works fine.

Let's say I want to make a GET request to just get updates on 2 of the 15 properties because they constantly change.  I dont want to return the full message payload so I only want to return the 2 properties.

```
{
    message_id: "526ee1b1ebf44af911010889",
    numberFollowers: 20,
    isHot: false,
}
```

How would I go about doing this and merging the data into the Messages already stored in Core Data?  Is this possible?  Are there any examples?

Thank You

Comment: I believe you would have to pass in some argument to your get request and have your server limit the data returned.

Comment: I am not concerned with how I will GET the data.  I need to know how to merge the new data into the existing Message record.

Answer (score 0):

On your mapping you need to teach RestKit how to find existing instances of the entity. You have the `_id` which looks like a unique identity so that can be used. To do this you use the `primaryKeyAttribute` of the mapping.

```
mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"_id"
```

(or whatever `_id` is mapped to in the entity).

Comment: So you are saying that if the response with only the 2 properties has the same _id then it should just update and keep the other data in the Message?  I do already have the primaryKeyAttribute set.  But the way the response is now it specifies message_id separate.

Comment: If you have set `primaryKeyAttribute`, yes. But the response does need to include that identity information.

Comment: Mapping 2 different source keys to the same destination key won't work (in a single mapping). You should really send the same key names in both responses...

Comment: Yeah I can do that, if its that simple, then great...i'll let you know.  thanks